# Server-based embedded database

Tags: c++, sql, database

I'm trying to figure out which database would suit my needs. My c++ project need a database that will be running on devices sold to customers. Mainly it would only log data and events to a database on local SSD disk. Write speed is the most important as logging frequency can be up to 1000Hz (1 write per 1ms). It must be possible to access data remotely from other devices to make graphic visualisations of data. I have tested sqlite with 3rd party server, mysql and postgres. Postgres seems to be quite slow compared to others. As I've read Postgres will become good if concurrency will increase, but in my case concurrency is and will be quite low.
I'm wondering is there any other database for such needs. It also feels that mysql and postgres will be a litte overkill for such requirements. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not so much embedded device actually - running atom processor and having 1 GB of RAM + SSD disk. Also the database code should be cross-platform. SQLite's concern is that it doesn't have a licence free reliable server. Postgres would be fine, as it's open source and free, but as far as I have tested it's way too slow on writes compared to SQLite or MySQL. Could it be so? MySQL would be a good option if it would only be free to use. As I've understood the server part is free to use but the official connectors are licenced. And as I need a C++ connector there are none in the community list.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL is an enterprise quality database, and not fit for embedded devices. MySQL while smaller will also be a tight fit in an embedded device. SQLite is the most common, and is widely used in embedded devices, even quite small.

Answer (score 1):

Go for sqlite because your requirement states that your App will be running on DEVICES and I guess, mostly they are mobile devices and almost all mobile devices support sqlite.... so go for it...

Answer (score 0):

Consider BerkeleyDB. It is a small-footprint embedded DB with a big commercial backer if you needed support, etc. There are open source versions as well as commercially licensed ones. There's no support for SQL querying, but unless you're doing quite complex relational queries this should not be a problem. Concurrency support is excellent, though initial database configuration tends to be awkward.

There's a Microsoft-only alternative in the form of the Extensible Storage Engine, that's free and available on most versions of Windows. There are various other 'DBM'-like simple embedded databases out there, so long as you don't feel you need SQL.

You might also consider an in-memory 'NoSQL'-style database; something like Redis will be very performant.

Answer (score 0):

[RDM Embedded](http://www.raima.com/products/rdm-embedded/) may be a good fit for you.  I'm with Raima and this product allows you to access data remotely and you can utilize the in-memory or a hybrid on-disk/in-memory database capabilities (www.raima.com/in-memory-database) if you need to.  What could be useful for you in this particular case is that RDM products can be used together to manage data between embedded, mobile, desktop or server devices.  This can be easily setup through our products, RDM Embedded, RDM Mobile, RDM Workgroup and RDM Server.

If you want to test performance of our database quickly before downloading the full product, go to our [Database Performance Popcorn Samples](http://www.raima.com/performance/).

Answer (score -1):

I hope this answer would help you with your embedded C++ project as I’m trying to revive this old thread that is still a significant requirement for developers who need a fast and lightweight database for their embedded and IoT applications.

you might want to consider using ObjectBox, which is a fast and lightweight database for C++ that is designed for embedded and IoT devices. According to its [GitHub page](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-c), ObjectBox offers the following features:

- High performance: up to 10x faster than SQLite
- Small footprint: less than 1 MB binary size
- ACID compliance: transactions, concurrency, and crash safety
- Schema migration: automatic and code-first
- Data synchronization: sync data between devices and servers
- Cross-platform: runs on Linux, Windows, macOS, Android, iOS, and more
- Easy to use: intuitive and modern C++ API

ObjectBox might suit your needs because it can handle high write speeds, store data locally on SSD disks, and allow remote access via data synchronization. You can also use ObjectBox Explorer, a web-based tool, to visualize and query your data. You can find more information and documentation on how to use ObjectBox on its [website](https://objectbox.io/).